# How to count number of SQL statements in text file?

Tags: mysql, sql, parsing

My program restores a MySQL database from SQL file. If I wanted to display progress of SQL execution in my program, I would need to know the number of SQL statements in the file. How can I do this in MySQL? (The queries may consist of mysql specific multi-row insert statements)

I could use either MySQL command line tools or the Python API. You're welcome to post solutions for other DBMS too.

Comment: Depending on your SQL data, a 'statement' might be simple or complex, with lots of data or without...so your progress indicator may not be very consistent.

Comment: I'm well aware of the limitations of this query count based approach, but otherwise how would you display progress in % or with a progress bar?

Answer (score 4):

The simple (and easy) way: Add `PRINT` statements to your SQL script file, displaying progess messages.

The advantage (apart from the obvious 'it's hard to parse multi-statement constructs') is that you get precise control over the progress. For example, some statements might take much longer to run than others so you would need to weight them.

I wouldn't think of progress in terms of number of statements executed. What I do is print out feedback that specific tasks have been started and completed, such as 'Synchronising Table 'blah'', 'Updating Stored Procedure X'  etc

Answer (score 3):

The naive solution is to count the number of semicolons in the file (or any other character used as delimited in the file).

It usually works pretty well, except when the data you are inserting has many semicolons and then you have to start dealing with actual parsing of the SQLs, which is a headache.